# Webserver max CPU when apache and MYSQL are ran together

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, cpu-usage

This website has been running fine without issues, Recently it went down.

After some investigation it looks like the combo of MYSQL and Apache bring the box to its knees. Apache can run find serving static web pages and MYSQL can run fine when the website isn't working.

As soon as the website is enabled with SQL running the CPU on the box remains at 100%.

Picture of the usage:

[image]

I've checked the sql database for errors, tried tuning nearly every parameter in apache/sql's conf file for performance. The server is a redhat based box running the latest software packages.

Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Doing an strace on a high cpu apache process I see the following:

```
read(14, "", 8192)                      = 0
close(14)                               = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 14
fcntl64(14, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY)          = 0
fcntl64(14, F_GETFL)                    = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
connect(14, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"...}, 110) = 0
setsockopt(14, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\2003\341\1\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
setsockopt(14, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "\2003\341\1\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
setsockopt(14, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4)  = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
setsockopt(14, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
```

Here is what I see from a mysql process:

```
futex(0x86fc9a4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 39, NULL) = 0
futex(0x86fc734, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0x86fc734, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
gettimeofday({1301465020, 141613}, NULL) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1301465020, 141699633}) = 0
futex(0x8707a64, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, {4, 999913367}) = 0
futex(0x8707a40, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0x8707a40, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: Is this server a VPS or dedicated system? The top stats you posted don't make much sense. The CPU is at 100% but the load near zero (0.66 0.20 is very low). Similarly, the CPU usage of the MySQL/httpd processes are 25% but the TIME+ column shows almost no net usage (unless you restarted both apps just seconds prior to this).

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you've tweaked Apache but is this a low traffic site ? Have you tried keeping the child instances of Apache right down: [MaxSpareServers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html).

You could check `ps -ef` to look closer at the `%CPU` column per process. If it's a *simple* site on older hardware you could test `lighthttpd` as a fix.

Sorry these suggestions are a bit finger-in-the-air.

Comment: It's a relatively low traffic site. In my original post there was a break down of the CPU hogs. Typically once apaache is started httpd starts eatting CPU, then MYSQL quickly creeps up until they are both running so hot the system barely is able to do anything else (including respond to SSH, commands, etc).

Comment: Updated some strace info to the original post. Hopefully that helps a little..

Comment: I'm not the man for this job, Tim :-( Other than suggesting that you upgrade to the latest versions of Apache and MySQL without getting my hands dirty, by logging in, nothing springs to mind I'm afraid. I'd look at an intermediate fix with another Web Server if all else fails: `http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Lighttpd_vs_nginx`